# py.test doesn't *seem* to run all tests - and doesn't fail - what is going on?

Tags: python, pytest

### Context

I've been following a tutorial, and have got the code to work, although the problem that I seem to have is -  there are 6 tests in my testing class, and on running the test, instead of seeing "collected 6 items", I see "collected 5 items". I suspect that the test "test_new_filename" is not running.

Is this the intended behaviour of pytest, or is something wrong with my code ?

### Source Code

Here's the base module: assignment4.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os


class ConfigDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        # if path not valid - then raise IOError
        if not os.path.isfile(self._filename):
            try:
                open(self._filename, 'w').close()
            except IOError:
                raise IOError('arg to configdict must be a valid path')
        with open(self._filename) as fp:
            for line in fp:
                line = line.rstrip()
                key, val = line.split('=', 1)
                dict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):

        # dict.self[key] = value
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)

        if os.path.isfile(self._filename):
            with open(self._filename, 'w') as fw:
                for key, val in self.items():
                    fw.write('{0}={1}\n'.format(key, val))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not key in self:
            raise ConfigKeyError(self, key)
        return dict.__getitem__(self, key)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self._filename


class ConfigKeyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, dictionary, key):
        self.key = key
        self.keys = dictionary.keys()

    def __str__(self):
        # print 'calling str'
        return "The key: {0} does not exist in mydict, avialable keys are {1}".format(self.key, self.keys)
```

Here's the testing module: test_assignment4.py

```
from assignment4 import ConfigDict, ConfigKeyError

import os
import pytest
import shutil

class TestConfigDict:
    existing_fn = 'config_file.txt'
    existing_fn_template = 'config_file_template.txt'
    new_fn = 'config_file_new.txt'
    bad_path = '/some/awful/path/that/doesnt/exist/file.txt'

    def setup_class(self):
        shutil.copy(TestConfigDict.existing_fn_template,
                    TestConfigDict.existing_fn)

    def teardown_class(self):
        os.remove(TestConfigDict.new_fn)

    # checking if the object is what we expect
    def test_obj(self):
        cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
        assert isinstance(cd, ConfigDict)
        assert isinstance(cd, dict)

    # check if the filename gets changed/set in the instance
    # assuming that the file exists
    def test_new_filename(self):
        cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
        assert cd._filename == TestConfigDict.existing_fn

    # check if using a new filename results in a new file
    # check if using new filename results in the _filename
    #   gets changed in the new instance
    # check if file actually gets created
    def test_new_filename(self):
        assert not os.path.isfile(TestConfigDict.new_fn)
        cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.new_fn)
        assert cd._filename == TestConfigDict.new_fn
        assert os.path.isfile(cd._filename)

    # it should throw an IO error, as the file does not exist
    def test_bad_filepath(self):
        with pytest.raises(IOError):
            ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.bad_path)

    def test_read_dict(self):
        cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
        assert cd['a'] == '5'
        assert cd['b'] == '10'
        assert cd['c'] == 'this=that'

        with pytest.raises(ConfigKeyError):
            print cd['x']

    def test_write_dict(self):
        cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
        cd['zz'] = 'top'
        cd2 = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
        assert cd2['zz'] == 'top'
```

and finally, here is the test file template: config_file_template.txt

```
a=5
b=10
c=this=that
```

### Observed Behaviour

This is the output that i see when running `py.test assignment4.py` :
[image]

### What I've tried

I've attempted to comment out the other tests, and leave test "test_new_filename" ; and it shows "collected 1 item" - which is good (I think) ; however, if i leave all tests uncommented, I see only 5!

Comment: The thing to do to convince yourself that the test framework is working is to make a deliberately failing test. eg: `def test_fail(self): assert False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two tests with the same name:

```
# check if the filename gets changed/set in the instance
# assuming that the file exists
def test_new_filename(self):
    cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.existing_fn)
    assert cd._filename == TestConfigDict.existing_fn

# check if using a new filename results in a new file
# check if using new filename results in the _filename
#   gets changed in the new instance
# check if file actually gets created
def test_new_filename(self):
    assert not os.path.isfile(TestConfigDict.new_fn)
    cd = ConfigDict(TestConfigDict.new_fn)
    assert cd._filename == TestConfigDict.new_fn
    assert os.path.isfile(cd._filename)
```

The second definition overrides the first by standard Python name-clobbering rules. The first test can therefore only be found if the second doesn't exist. You can fix this by just changing the names of the test (I recommend making them more specific; move some of that context out of the comments and into the name of the test).

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that >< The IDE (PyCharm) did highlight it, although no squiggly lines - oh well, lesson learned!